# Show the output of Powershell script in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have a WPF application that executes a Powershell script and then displays a message in a textbox in the application. The Powershell script is executed like this:

```
string scriptPath = folderPath + "/EXECUTE.ps1";
string powershellPath = @"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
string outputLog = folderPath + "output.log";

bool is64 = IntPtr.Size == 8;
var ENV = "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* "
       + (is64 ? ",HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*" : "")
       + " | Select-Object DisplayName";
ProcessStartInfo startInstall = new ProcessStartInfo(powershellPath, ENV);
startInstall.UseShellExecute = false;
startInstall.Arguments = scriptPath;
startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardOutput", "true");
startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardError", "true");
startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("UseShellExecute", "false");
startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("CreateNoWindow", "true");
Process Install = Process.Start(startInstall);
Install.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Script executed successfully");
Console.WriteLine("Output available at: " + outputLog);
```

The last two lines in `Console.WriteLine` are printed out in a textbox. I was wondering, is there a way that I can show the output of the Powershell terminal window inside of this textbox named `txtboxExecutionResult`? I am not executing any Powershell command from my application, just starting and executing the `EXECUTE.ps1` file from the application. I'd really appreciate any help to point me in some direction.

Comment: The output of a PowerShell goes to standard output so you have to read the standard output.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once with reading output from another application and I solved it by reading the standard output of the process.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "example.exe";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
process.Start();
output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```